# Woocommerce - How to hide trailing zeros after the 2nd decimal place?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

So I have a question I was hoping somebody might be able to help me out with...
 I have a WordPress website that uses WooCommerce and I'm trying to do something relatively specific. The site has a fair deal of bulk pricing discounts for various products.
Now when it comes to the bulk pricing I kind of need the calculations to be done with four decimal places (i.e. $0.1234), So I have the WooCommerce settings set so that the number of decimals is 4.
The thing is, that on a lot of our products we don't have bulk pricing discounts; in most of these cases the four decimal places are completely unnecessary. (For example: $0.5500 or $12.0000) Is there any way I can trim the trailing the zeros but only if it is after the second decimal place?
For example, if I had $0.5500 it would be displayed as $0.55 and if I had $12.0000 it would be displayed as $12.00
I know a very similar question was asked a few years ago ([see here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18021111/how-to-delete-trailing-zeros-after-the-3rd-decimal-place-in-php)), but unfortunately, the answer that worked in that case does not seem to work for me... That being said, I could be trying to use it the wrong way. I am not very familiar with using regular expressions in a WordPress "functions.php" file.
Any help at all would be greatly appreciated! Thanks!

Edit:
At this point I have something along the lines of:

```
add_action('wc_price', 'custom_price_disp');
function custom_price_disp($price) {
    $count = null;
    $resultingPrice = preg_replace('/(?<=\d{2})(0+)$/', '', $price, -1, $count);
    return $resultingPrice;
}
```

But this code does not seem to work. Prices are still displayed the same as they were before.

Comment: The function you need to customize is: [wc_price()](http://woocommerce.wp-a2z.org/oik_api/wc_price/)

Comment: @wittich Okay, that's definitely good to know. But that brings me to another question; what is the most efficient way to customize a WooCommerce function? Every time I've done this in the past it's turned out to be somewhat messy. Is there a "correct" way of going about it that I am not aware of?

Answer (score 3):

You can use this function in your `functions.php` child theme, it works fine and removes `.00` from every price:

```
add_filter('woocommerce_price_trim_zeros', 'wc_hide_trailing_zeros', 10, 1);
function wc_hide_trailing_zeros( $trim ) {
    // set to false to show trailing zeros
    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I’ve not used it myself, but based on the aforementioned `wc_price()` method’s code, it *looks* like you can take advantage of a filter:

```
if ( apply_filters( 'woocommerce_price_trim_zeros', false ) && $decimals > 0 ) {
  $price = wc_trim_zeros( $price );
}
```

You should be able to add this to your `functions.php`:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_price_trim_zeros', true );
```

To trigger this behavior.

Comment: Thanks, first of all I appreciate the answer. I have tried simply using add_filter( 'woocommerce_price_trim_zeros', true ); but this trims any and all decimal zeros. What I'm trying to do is to only trim the zeros after the 2nd decimal place.

Comment: Right; that makes sense. This is quite a bit trickier, in that case! You might need to refactor the [`wc_trim_zeros()` function](http://woocommerce.wp-a2z.org/oik_api/wc_trim_zeros/). You could also, instead of passing `true` as the 2nd argument of that `add_filter()`, instead pass it a function that mimics `wc_trim_zeros()`, but does what you need.